# Question on limits of Lebesgue measurable function. (Additional conditions?)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

[image]

I feel that there might be a problem with this question or there needs to be more conditions imposed on the functions $f_n$ i.e. integrability etc.

My initial thought was to use Monotone convergence on $f_n-g$. Hence, $\int f_n-g d\mu=\int f-g d\mu$ . Then I add $\int g d\mu$ on both sides. But to show that $\int f_n-gd\mu+ \int gd\mu=\int f_n-g+g d\mu$ requires that $f_n-g$ is integrable. Same goes for $f-g$.

Any suggestions or was my method wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Integral is defined for all non-negative measurable functions, integrable or not. $\int (f-g) d\mu+\int g d\mu=\int f d\mu$ is valid whenever $f\geq g$ and $g$ is integrable.  Note that $\int fd\mu$ makes sense because $\int f^{-} d\mu <\infty$. Indeed, $0\leq f^{-} \leq g^{-} \leq |g|$.

Comment: Isn't $\int fd\mu $ by definition supposed to be finite (f being any real valued function)? The integral can be infinite but for only positive functions. You have only shown that the integral of the negative part is less than infinity not the positive part.

Comment: @JhonDoe $\int fd\mu$ is defined (with possible values $\pm \infty$) whenever $f$ is measurable and either $\int f^{-}d\mu <\infty$ or $\int f^{+}d\mu <\infty$. I don't know which book you are following but these are standard facts. Certainly Rudin's book will give you these facts.